# How to separate string and integers to a list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, int

I need to separate this string:

```
s = "I have 10 cars"
```

to a list like this:

```
['I','h','a','v','e',10,'c','a','r','s']
```

The digits shouldn't be separated. also digit should entered as a Integer( without these ' ')

Comment: Great! Good luck with it! Ask a descriptive question with what you have tried and researched so far if you get stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res = []
for item in s.split(' '):
...     try:
...         int(item)
...         res.append(item)
...     except:
...         res += list(item)
```

Comment: `append` and `+=` are really expensive for `list`, given that you need to resize it every time

Comment: @Brian append will create list of list

Comment: `append` and `extend` (or `+=` as you use) should be avoided if you have the chance. Both operations cause Python to have to resize the array in memory and because of that, it's not very efficient. Your method works, but for longer strings, it will be an expensive operation

Comment: @Brian true. agree with you

Comment: res = []
for item in input().split(' '):
    try:
        res.append(int(item))
    except:
        res += list(item)
print(res)

Answer (score 2):

> The other answers here are terribly inefficient for larger strings.

You should **not** unnecessarily use `append`, since it could be very costly with larger strings. In my way, you do not resize your `list` each time you find a new element you need in it. In the interest of efficiency, you can do it like so:

```
s = "I have 10 cars"

def seperateWithInts( l ):
    for s in l.split():
        if s.isdigit():
            yield s
        else:
            for c in s:
                yield c

s2 = [i for i in seperateWithInts(s)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner using list comprehension which is probably not your best option.

```
s = "I have 10 cars"
print [item for sublist in [[x] if x.isdigit() else list(x) for x in s.split(" ")] for item in sublist]
#Output
['I', 'h', 'a', 'v', 'e', '10', 'c', 'a', 'r', 's']
```

Basically, you split the string into a list of lists which contains the chars and the number, then you flatten the lists, all in one fell swoop of list comprehension.

Answer (score -4):

Try to return it as a string.

```
list(str("I have 10 cars"))
```

Comment: Why am I being down voted?

Comment: That doesn't work. Try running it yourself

Comment: Your answer is wrong. It produces `['I','h','a','v','e','1','0','c','a','r','s']`, i.e. it splits the number as well. Also, the use of `str` is unneeded.